# Create app folder in One drive for business - Privileges

Tags: onedrive, office365api

I am working on file uploader to One Drive for Business account.
My application should have the least privileged access as possible duo security reasons.

I can authenticate and generate correct tokens, but I cannot create App Folder when I have only that access: Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder. I got below response:
{"error":{"code":"accessDenied","message":"The caller does not have permission to perform the action."}}

When I extended my privileges to Files.ReadWrite.All the same request succeeded.
Request: GET https://{tenant}-my.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.0/me/drive/special/approot/

I known correctly tenant, I just haven't provided it in that post.

Does One Drive for Business work with App Folder privileges? I am not sure according to below document:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/drive_get_specialfolder

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the `Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder` does not work for OneDrive Business ([see this documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference#remarks-5)). It's something we definitely want to fix.

Comment: https://onedrive.uservoice.com/forums/262982-onedrive/suggestions/33911101-make-files-readwrite-appfolder-work-with-onedrive

Comment: Any news about Files.ReadWrite.AppFolder support for business and education?

Comment: Hello, any update on this? Maybe some workaround?